# can't show/display image from mongodb to directly react js component

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am new to MERN stack. I have already tried a lot of youtube videos and google searches to show/display the images stored in mongodb as the schema :

```
photograph: {
  data : Buffer,
  contentType : String
}
```

It saved successfully in mongodb after few efforts. I tried to convert it into base64 as done by other youtubers but still no results so far.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

All of the commented out- (img tags) and array.map functions  -> (because i tried to convert my data to array instead of json and then use .map function) are the things i have already tried. I am trying to understand the basics here. so please suggest me simple methods to do it. Also remember that {user.name} {user.dateOfBirth} , etc type of all other data showing successfully.

[image]